# Can I just call a spring integration chain element directly from the java code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-integration

For unit testing purposes I was wondering if it is possible to call just a certain portion of the spring integration workflow, like say, a chain element from the java code?

Comment: Probably, but it's not at all clear what exactly you want to do. Generally speaking, you should just create an unmanaged instance in your unit test.

Comment: Your question is too vague, In unit testing you are just mocking your services and see your business logic works fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

One of first class-citizen in the Spring Integration is `MessageChannel`. The `<chain>` does not have difference with many other endpoints from the Spring Integration family and it isn't a secret that `<chain>` has `input-channel` as well. So, you can just inject that channel to your unit-test and send a message to it. But you should understand that it won't be `a certain portion`, because the sending message to that chain's channel will be processed fully in the downstream flow.

Yes, you maybe need to think about some mocking after chain to avoid whole business process.